# sqoop export to hana failed

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, sqoop

when I want to export data from sqoop to hana DB, I receive error message.

Here is sqoop call

```
sqoop export \
 --connect "jdbc:sap://saphana:30115" \
 --username username \
 --password password \
 --table "INTERFACE_BO.WR_CUSTOMER_DATA" \
 --columns "WEEK_DAY_START,SALES_ORG,REG_ORDERS_CNT,REG_EMAILS_CNT,UNIQUE_EMAILS" \ 
 --driver "com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver" \      
 --export-dir "/user/hive/warehouse/export.db/weekly_holding_report" \
 --input-fields-terminated-by '\t'
```

This is the way how I create table

```
CREATE TABLE weekly_holding_report
    ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
    stored as textfile
AS
SELECT
...
```

I also tried many variants of stored as like: stored as parquet, etc.. but without any change

And here is reposponse

```
Warning: /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.8.0-1.cdh5.8.0.p0.42/bin/../lib/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
16/10/25 06:43:04 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6-cdh5.8.0
16/10/25 06:43:04 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
16/10/25 06:43:05 WARN sqoop.ConnFactory: Parameter --driver is set to an explicit driver however appropriate connection manager is not being set (via --connection-manager). Sqoop is going to fall back to org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager. Please specify explicitly which connection manager should be used next time.
16/10/25 06:43:05 INFO manager.SqlManager: Using default fetchSize of 1000
16/10/25 06:43:05 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
16/10/25 06:43:05 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM INTERFACE_BO.WR_CUSTOMER_DATA AS t WHERE 1=0
16/10/25 06:43:05 INFO orm.CompilationManager: HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME is /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hadoop-mapreduce
Note: /tmp/sqoop-root/compile/515ace5e3ad6ad117ba5f5fa61bf279c/INTERFACE_BO_WR_CUSTOMER_DATA.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
16/10/25 06:43:07 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Writing jar file: /tmp/sqoop-root/compile/515ace5e3ad6ad117ba5f5fa61bf279c/INTERFACE_BO.WR_CUSTOMER_DATA.jar
16/10/25 06:43:07 INFO mapreduce.ExportJobBase: Beginning export of INTERFACE_BO.WR_CUSTOMER_DATA
16/10/25 06:43:07 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.jar is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.jar
16/10/25 06:43:07 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.map.max.attempts is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.maxattempts
16/10/25 06:43:08 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.reduce.tasks.speculative.execution is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.reduce.speculative
16/10/25 06:43:08 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.map.tasks.speculative.execution is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.speculative
16/10/25 06:43:08 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.map.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.maps
16/10/25 06:43:08 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at cz-dc-v-564.mall.local/10.200.58.21:8032
16/10/25 06:43:10 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 10
16/10/25 06:43:10 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 10
16/10/25 06:43:10 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:4
16/10/25 06:43:10 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.map.tasks.speculative.execution is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.speculative
16/10/25 06:43:10 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1476740951886_1458
16/10/25 06:43:10 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1476740951886_1458
16/10/25 06:43:10 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://cz-dc-v-564.mall.local:8088/proxy/application_1476740951886_1458/
16/10/25 06:43:10 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1476740951886_1458
16/10/25 06:43:18 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1476740951886_1458 running in uber mode : false
16/10/25 06:43:18 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
16/10/25 06:43:25 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
16/10/25 06:43:25 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1476740951886_1458 failed with state FAILED due to: Task failed task_1476740951886_1458_m_000000
Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0

16/10/25 06:43:26 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 13
    Job Counters 
        Failed map tasks=1
        Killed map tasks=3
        Launched map tasks=4
        Data-local map tasks=1
        Rack-local map tasks=3
        Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=39746
        Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0
        Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=19873
        Total vcore-seconds taken by all map tasks=19873
        Total megabyte-seconds taken by all map tasks=30524928
    Map-Reduce Framework
        CPU time spent (ms)=0
        Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=0
        Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=0
16/10/25 06:43:26 WARN mapreduce.Counters: Group FileSystemCounters is deprecated. Use org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.FileSystemCounter instead
16/10/25 06:43:26 INFO mapreduce.ExportJobBase: Transferred 0 bytes in 17,9084 seconds (0 bytes/sec)
16/10/25 06:43:26 INFO mapreduce.ExportJobBase: Exported 0 records.
16/10/25 06:43:26 ERROR tool.ExportTool: Error during export: Export job failed!
```

Does anybody know what am I doing wrong?

Thanks for help!

Comment: try with `--verbose` in the end of your command (_to see extended logs_)

Comment: Are you able to read from the hana DB? Try a simple select of 1 row and store it as a textfile. -- If that fails its probably a connection issue, if that works try specifying the actual insert query (which you were able to use without sqoop), as you may get a more usefull error message.

Comment: **http://cz-dc-v-564.mall.local:8088/proxy/application_1476740951886_1458/** Navigate to this job url, You should be able to view the detail log of the failed task - **task_1476740951886_1458_m_000000**, there must be some **Exception**.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding an sqoop argumment --m 1

this is basically for giving number of mappers so in this case try with mapper = 1

is your data is too huge(more than 1 gb's) then increase number of mappers

Comment: **data> 1gb** is not the only parameter for using multiple mappers.

Comment: @devツ : i agree , but for running the query he can try with this argument. yes their are more parameters to be considered for giving mapper number.

Answer (score 0):

Check the logs for the corresponding job id, in your case `job_1476740951886_1458`. There must be some permission or connectivity issue(with the given saphana url), that is why it transferred zero bytes.